# How to resolve java.awt.HeadlessException?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to convert desktop application JCBIR(http://code.google.com/p/jcbir/) to web applicatin(SpringMVC). On my development environment
Windows 7, 64 bit
Jdk jdk1.7.0_09
Tomcat 6.18

Working without any error.

But when I try to deploy the same on other machine
Windows 7, 32 bit
Jdk 6.0.21
Tomcat 6.18

It gives java.awt.HeadlessException

Any pointer to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I turn off headless graphics environment on windows7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019802/how-can-i-turn-off-headless-graphics-environment-on-windows7)

Comment: Running without head throws it.

Comment: i have set -Djava.awt.headless=true in tomcat/bin/setenv.bat. but still same issue

Comment: and desktop application working on the same system without any issue

Comment: Err, don't call AWT or Swing classes or APIs? Such as the one in the stack trace? The one you didn't post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but reconfigure all the environment with fresh tomcat, now its working for me.